# Custom sorting in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a particular column "TENOR" on the basis on maturity (group by Currencies) for eg - it should be sorted in the following order ON, SW, 1M, 2M, 3M, 6M, 9M, 1Y, 18M, 2Y and so on.. where ON = Overnight, SW = Single week and 1M = 1 month. i have tried using order by case but not sure what I am missing it always gives 18M on the top of the result.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DECODE` (or `CASE`) statement (and could put meaningful values) and, since you are getting a 3-character sub-string, you need to include the trailing space:

If a simplified version of your query is:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( name, 9, 3 ) AS tenor,
       name
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY SUBSTR( name, 1, 8 ),
         DECODE(
           tenor,
           'ON ', 1/30,
           'SW ', 7/30,
           '1M ', 1,
           '2M ', 2,
           '3M ', 3,
           '6M ', 6,
           '9M ', 9,
           '1Y ', 12,
           '18M', 18,
           '2Y ', 24,
           '3Y ', 36,
           '5Y ', 60,
           '10Y', 120,
           NULL
         ) ASC NULLS LAST
```

For the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( name ) AS
SELECT 'ARZ USD 18M FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BRZ USD 10Y FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ARZ USD 1Y FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ARZ USD 2M FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BRZ USD 1M FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ARZ USD 6M FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ARZ USD 3M FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ARZ USD 1M FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ARZ USD 9M FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BRZ USD 1Y FX FORWARD' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> TENOR | NAME                  
> :---- | :---------------------
> 1M    | ARZ USD 1M FX FORWARD 
> 2M    | ARZ USD 2M FX FORWARD 
> 3M    | ARZ USD 3M FX FORWARD 
> 6M    | ARZ USD 6M FX FORWARD 
> 9M    | ARZ USD 9M FX FORWARD 
> 1Y    | ARZ USD 1Y FX FORWARD 
> 18M   | ARZ USD 18M FX FORWARD
> 1M    | BRZ USD 1M FX FORWARD 
> 1Y    | BRZ USD 1Y FX FORWARD 
> 10Y   | BRZ USD 10Y FX FORWARD
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f1ae7dc3e90b65c8f87744a66eba313f)*

Answer (score 1):

Would you try this code? "table1" is the CTE for data preparation to test. by using **regexp_substr** function with pattern **'\w+'** *got the third word* from text and **'\d+'** got the first digit. Then for the right sorting converted the years to months by multiplying digits by 12, and gave default values for 'ON' -1, 'SW' 1 then sorted them asc.

```
with table1("name") 
as (
    select 'ARZ USD 18M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'ARZ USD 1M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'ARZ USD 1Y FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'ARZ USD 2M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'ARZ USD 3M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'ARZ USD 6M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 10Y FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 1M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 1Y FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 2M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 2Y FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 3M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 3Y FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 5Y FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 6M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 7Y FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD 9M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'CLZ USD 1M FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD ON FX FORWARD' from dual union all
    select 'BRZ USD SW FX FORWARD' from dual 
)
select 
    regexp_substr("name",'\w+',1,3) as tenor,
    -------------------
    t.* 
from table1 t
order by nvl(to_number(regexp_substr("name",'\d+',1,1)),1)*decode(substr(regexp_substr("name",'\w+',1,3),-1),'M',1,'Y', 12, 'N', -1, 'W', 0,-999) asc
;
```

result is as below

```
TENOR   name
ON      BRZ USD ON FX FORWARD
SW      BRZ USD SW FX FORWARD
1M      ARZ USD 1M FX FORWARD
1M      CLZ USD 1M FX FORWARD
1M      BRZ USD 1M FX FORWARD
2M      BRZ USD 2M FX FORWARD
2M      ARZ USD 2M FX FORWARD
3M      BRZ USD 3M FX FORWARD
3M      ARZ USD 3M FX FORWARD
6M      BRZ USD 6M FX FORWARD
6M      ARZ USD 6M FX FORWARD
9M      BRZ USD 9M FX FORWARD
1Y      BRZ USD 1Y FX FORWARD
1Y      ARZ USD 1Y FX FORWARD
18M     ARZ USD 18M FX FORWARD
2Y      BRZ USD 2Y FX FORWARD
3Y      BRZ USD 3Y FX FORWARD
5Y      BRZ USD 5Y FX FORWARD
7Y      BRZ USD 7Y FX FORWARD
10Y     BRZ USD 10Y FX FORWARD
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting by `name`, then decoded `tenor`. But the `name` has a standard prefix followed by the tenor value. So all the names with the same prefix are going to be sorted by the tenor name.

The solution would be to sort by the prefix then the decoded tenor:

```
order by trim(substr(name,1,8))
         , case when tenor = ...
```

Also, the code you use for extracting the tenor contains a bug. Your substring is three characters long but many tenors are only two characters long: so you are extracting `'ON '` with a trailing space but in the CASE statement you are checking for `'ON'`, which won't match the extracted substring. I suggest you trim the extracted tenor:

```
rtrim(substr(name,9,3)) as tenor
```

---

> i have tried the above-mentioned solution but still 18M is coming before 1M

Yes, that's interesting. I've reproduced it. I'm not sure why it happens but I have fixed it by apply a trim to the `substr()`. Here is [a working demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0926b154576e692cb66fa6e2063c0482).

Comment: Thanks APC i have tried the above-mentioned solution but still 18M is coming before 1M